# Make Gradle build halt/fail on failing Exec task based on output

Tags: jenkins, gradle, webpack

We use an Exec task for running Webpack in our Gradle build definition. 
This task fails sometimes, but the build task completes and our Jenkins server thinks everything went well and publishes the war file with corrupt client code in it.

In the output from the Exec task you can see that Webpack gets an error and halts.

I now wonder if it is possible to make my Exec task consume the output and react on it before exiting so that i can make the task fail.

i have played with setStandardOutput() and standardOutput, but i cannot seem to get it to work.

Below is my task definition

```
task webpack(type: Exec) {
    def mainCommand = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? 'webpack.cmd' : 'webpack'

    if (project.environment == 'prod')
        commandLine mainCommand, '-p'
    else
        commandLine mainCommand
}
```

Comment: The standard way to tell if an exec task passed is the exit value. If the exec command returns a non-zero exit value, gradle fails the build. What does your task return on failure?

Comment: My issue is that i am not able to tell if it fails or not

Comment: See if this snippet helps: https://gist.github.com/lifuzu/10671707

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work fine for me. It parses the output and if the output contains a line that begins with "error" the task fails.

```
task webpack(type: Exec) {
    def mainCommand = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? 'webpack.cmd' : 'webpack'
        standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        if (project.environment == 'prod')
            commandLine mainCommand, '-p'
        else
            commandLine mainCommand

    doLast {
        String output = standardOutput.toString()

        if(output.readLines().any{line->line.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith("error")}) {
            throw new GradleException("Error in WebPack: \n${output}")
        } else {
            println "Great success! Output is: ${output}"
        }
    }

}
```